# Compactification of the upper half plane

Tags: riemann-surfaces, compactification

Consider the upper half plane $\mathbb{H} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \text{im}(z) > 0 \}$ as a Riemann surface.

I suspect that the compactification of $\mathbb{H}$ is the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$. Or maybe it's just a point $*$?

How would I find the compactification of $\mathbb{H}$?

Comment: There is no such a thing as "**the** compactification." The most natural compactification in this setting is homeomorphic to the closed disk.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Suppose I define "the" compactification of $X$, $\overline{X}$, as a compact Riemann surface $C$ with a map $X \rightarrow C$, which is universal as such in the category of Riemann surfaces (when it exists). Is it possible to show that this colimit does not exist?

Comment: what you wrote is not a definition: You have to spell what kind of a map it is and the universality property that it has. And you should modify the question, not write your definition as a comment.